# Why do some AlertDialogs disappear upon device rotation?

Tags: android, user-interface

When I change device orientation, if AlertDialog was shown, it disappears. This is true for all but one dialogs in my app, and I can't figure out neither what's so special about the one that doesn't disappear nor how to counteract this behaviour. Any possibility to preserve dialogs upon orientation change (except for manual management)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by many people here,

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

is not a solution. It's a hack at best. The correct way to handle this is to manage dialogs through your activity. You need to override a few methods in your activity code, Like so:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // create and return your dialog instance here
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.indicator_input_error)
        .setMessage(message)
        .create();
    dialog.setButton(
            DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,    
            context.getString(R.string.OK),
            (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) null);
    return dialog;
}

protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    // You dialog initialization code here
}
```

After you're done with this. You show your dialog using:

```
showDialog(yourDialogID);
```

Once you're done implementing this, your'll see that your dialog will also be recreated if configuration changes occur. The best part is that your `Activity` will manage your dialog for you. It will be reused when possible, reducing dialog load times if you perform heavy initialization.

> **[Note from Android SDK documentation:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config)**
>   Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the way for me since not all my dialogs are custom, I use alertBuilder a lot. But thanks for showing the right way.

Comment: By the way, `android:configChanges="orientation"` works perfectly, what's the catch? I've read about it's meaning, but still don't quite understand possible downsides.

Comment: If you use that attribute you're telling android not to recreate your activity when orientation changes. That is not the android way AFAIK. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config for details. There's a special note about avoiding this method. Also, you can return an alert dialog created using AlertDialog.Builder using the method outlined above.

Comment: I've modified my answer to show code that returns dialogs created by `AlertDialog.Builder`.

Comment: @CodePoet How would you know the dialogID ?

Comment: @h4ck3d dialogID is a random id you assign to your managed dialog

Comment: How would you assign an ID to a Dialog ? Is there any method for thT?

Comment: Check the latest documentation. This stuff is dated now.

Answer (score 9):

You can also override the onSaveInstanceState method and save a flag indicating whether or not your dialog was showing when the orientation changed.  You can then get that flag back from the bundle in onCreate and redisplay your dialog if needed.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);

    // Save the state so that it can be restored in onCreate or onRestoreInstanceState
    state.putBoolean("dialog_showing", dialog_showing);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getBoolean("dialog_showing", false)) {
        // Show your dialog again
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

Instead of restoring your state in `onCreate` you can also override the `onRestoreInstanceState` method.  It is called after `onStart` and will only be called if the bundle is not null; so you don't have to do the null check on the bundle as you would in the `onCreate` method.

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("dialog_showing", false)) {
        // Show your dialog again
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely the best solution while following the natural activity lifecycle. Just don't forget to define a global variable for the `AlertDialog` and dismiss it `onDestroy()` to prevent window leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I think probably Because OnCreate method is called upon orientation change  and activity is again created so dialog disappears.

Comment: Good Point. The Tag in my answer below will fix this issue.

Answer (score -5):

Its becuase the activity is restarting when you rotate the device.

If you add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Tag to each activity you dont want to restart on configuration change add the following tag.

Answer (score -6):

i think may be you have to take

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in mainfest of your activity

Answer (score -6):

when you rotate your device it restarts your activity that's why your dialog get disappear to solve this problem just include following attributes in your android-manifest xml

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```